# Escape Quote in jena untyped literal

Tags: java, escaping, rdf, jena

I want to add a untyped literal to an axiom in Jena.
The literal in the resulting rdf file should have a special form where quotes ""
are escaped by &quote\; (without \). The following 
example code is used, but when writing the ontology to an rdf file jena
does not escape the quotes.

```
// The following only to give a full example
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);

OntClass clazz        = model.createClass( ns + className);
Individual individual = model.createIndividual( ns +  individualName, clazz);
Resource axiom = model.createResource( OWL2.Axiom );

axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedSource, individual );
axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedTarget,  clazz );
axiom.addProperty( OWL2.annotatedProperty, RDF.type );

AnnotationProperty label = model.createAnnotationProperty( ns +"label" );

// IMPORTANT LINES:
String litString = "<tag type=\"axiom\"> Some Other Values </tag>"
Literal lit = model.createLiteral(litString);
axiom.addLiteral( label,  lit);
```

This would produce a literal like:

```
&lt;tag type="axiom"&gt; Some Other Values &lt;/tag&gt;
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
&lt;tag type=&quot;axiom&quot;&gt; Some Other Values &lt;/tag&gt;
```

Using &quot\; (without\) instead of " leads to an escape of & by &amp\; (without \). So this is also no solution, any sugestions ?

Comment: Could you proofread your question a bit and double check the characters?  It's not clear at the moment exactly what you want.  For instance, are you asking Jena to take a string containing `<tag type=\"axiom\"> Some Other Values </tag>"` and automatically encode the angle brackets so that you get `&lt;tag type="axiom"&gt; Some Other Values &lt;/tag&gt;`?

Comment: I think this probably doesn't have anything do with Jena, since you're just providing the lexical form of the literal as a string, and Jena's creating a literal with that string as a lexical form.  If you want to replace `"` by `&quot;`, I think you'd just do that to the string *before* creating the literal.

Comment: As I wrote above. Jena is doing some escaping by itself e.g. "<" is replaced by "&lt;" , > is replaced by "&gt;" and "&" is replaced by "&amp;". But quotes are not replaced! If I would replace them manualy before giving them to jena then jena would replace "&quot;" by "&amp;quot;". So this is a jena problem, right ?

Comment: In output for a plain string, it goes inside an XML tag where " is a legal character. e.g. <x>hello "world"</x> is legal XML. &quot; is not needed so it isn't done. Quoting < and > is needed for XML. &quot; is only needed for an attribute using "". The contract is that it gets read back in correctly, which it will do. If you use &quot; it will be &amp;&quot; because the string has &-q-u-o-t.